# Using Javascript to intercept links on development server

Tags: javascript

I have a pure HTML job which is being developed on a different server to the one it will be delivered on. The delivery server is a propriety system that only really allows you to upload the final HTML and to complicate matters it does its own URL rewriting, so I need to use absolute URL addressing between pages which means on the dev server clicking a link currently takes you to the live server page that doesn't exist yet. It's all just a bit unfriendly for testing.

One thing I can use to my advantage is the HTML you put on the live server is only the stuff between the body tags, so I'm thinking I can pop some Javascript in the head area that intercepts clicks on links starting with a specific URL and sends it to the dev server; something like:

"if URL starts with https://liveserver.com/ change start to https://devserver.com/"

That way the Javascript only appears on the dev server and won't do the redirect when the code is uploaded.

Don't really want to have to bother loading JQuery just for this (unless it makes it sooooo much easier), so is there a simple way of doing it in pure Javascript? prevent.default, perhaps?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is a great idea, but you could run a query selector and just replace all the hrefs.

Notice that after this runs both links point at stackoverflow:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a')
  .forEach(
    a => a.href = a.href.replace('google', 'stackoverflow')
  );
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 0;
  position: relative;
}
a::after {
  content: attr(href);
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com/google-link">Google</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/stack-overflow-link">Stack Overflow</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, and so simple.